# multi operating system for distributed computing in spark 2.1.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing, master-slave

Seeking Help

As I'm New to Spark just want to know.

I had setup spark master by changing spark-env.sh file changing parameters to

```
     export SCALA_HOME=/cats/dev/scala/scala-2.12.2
     export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
     export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=3
     export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/cats/dev/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/work/sparkdata
     export SPARK_MASTER_IP="192.168.1.54"
     export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
     export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
```

for a multi-node on the same machine

for executing small project I had to use the command

```
        (/cats/dev/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --class  "Person" --master spark://cats-All-Series:7077 /cats/sbt_projects/test/people/target/scala-2.10/people-assembly-1.0.jar
```

after executing when I check web UI my app finished time was 6 seconds. but when I deploy on a single without out master and slave the same got executed in 0.3 seconds.

without a master, I had executed in spark-shell firstly loaded the code

```
 (scala> :load /cats/scala/db2connectivity/sparkjdbc.scala) and executed(scala> sparkjdbc.connectSpark) for it.

>import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

>import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.List
import java.util.Properties


    object Person extends App {
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
        connectSpark()
        /*Following is spark-jdbc code using scala*/
        def connectSpark(): Unit ={

        val url = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/sample"
        val driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
        val username = "db2inst1"
        val password = "db2inst1"

        val prop = new java.util.Properties
        prop.setProperty("user",username)
        prop.setProperty("password",password)

        Class.forName(driver)

        val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("url", url)
        .option("driver", driver)
        .option("dbtable", "allbands")
        .option("user", "db2inst1")
        .option("password", "db2inst1")
        .load()

        jdbcDF.show()
        println("Done loading")

        }


        }
```

Comment: So what is the question ? Why it takes 6 seconds with spark-submit and 0.6 when you load it in spark-shell ?

Comment: @eliasah while deploying with spark-submit with 3 nodes it takes more time as compare with spark-shell . so my doubt is when i have  3 nodes my time should be less are compare to spark-shell

Comment: That code script you've shared doesn't return a result but it defines a module. Plus spark takes some time to set up the application context, etc.

Comment: @eliasah thanks , as i am aware the code-script which i have shared is used only to read table details. as  you said that application might be taking time to set up. being  spark new for me  can you suggest how time can be reduced

Comment: that code you shared read just when you submit it to spark and not when you load it into the spark-shell

Comment: @eliasah did you mean that during spark-submit it takes time to load all jars and setting up context whereas in spark-shell we do setup first and then load? if yes , i don't want to use spark-shell so how can i read in spark submit.

Comment: @eliasah thanks for the needful help  when i commented .load() and jdbcDF.show() from above shared code time got reduced from 6sec to 1sec.